# Nuget 2.* task in VSO/Azure dev-ops with command==custom option

Tags: nuget, azure-devops

Has anyone used the Nuget task version 2.* in VSO? I need to pass some arguments while packaging the nuget, hence I select the below option (command == custom)[image]

Now I need to pass arguments like "versioningScheme" and "versionEnvVar". How do I pass that to this task?

Shall I write like this in the "commands and argument" box? command:pack;versioningScheme:byEnvVar or any other pattern?  I am not able to find an appropriate documentation as well.

[This is the sole documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/nuget?view=vsts) I found and it doesnt say anything about how to pass the arguments.

Comment: When selecting 'pack' as command you can also set some additional properties in the advanced section, have you tried this ? what additional arguments do you need to set manually ?